# gh-pages ignoring project directory when searching for resources?

Tags: javascript, html, css, resources, github-pages

I have a website I have been working on that works just fine locally but when deployed to gh-pages has many 404's when trying to pull in resources.
For example, I have a line of css for the background which is

```
background: #fff url(/assets/images/bg.jpg) repeat top left;
```

the 404 I get is this{

```
github.io/assets/images/bg.jpg
```

The path should be

```
github.io/myProject/assets/images/bg.jpg
```

How can I change this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that in your local setup the assets folder is in the same directory.

Lets say your local path looks someting like this:
`file:///index.html` where your assets folder is a sibling to `index.html`. In this case it works because `/` goes to the beggining of the directory. which in this case is : `file:///` and there it see's the assets folder so it works locally.

On github now, you have a repo which is basically `my-project`. In `my-project` you have `index.html` and the folder `assets`. So when you say `/assets/` here the begginnig directory is `github.io` so it looks for `assets` there which obviously doesn't exist.

**Solution**
Dont add `/` before assets. As long as assets is in the same directory as where this code is written you should be fine.

Also take a closer look at relative paths to understand it better: http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

Comment: That worked! Also thanks a ton for that article, that cleared things up a lot.

Answer (score 0):

While gh-pages are generated by [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/), you can use his magic to ease development.

Create a `_config.yml` file at the root, containing :

```
baseurl: myProject/
```

You can now call any resource with `{{site.baseurl}}assets/images/bg.jpg` 
which will automatically translate to `myProject/assets/images/bg.jpg`.